# How to find a string in another string?

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to make a query that will find a specific word like "mark" in a string from my data base. I don't know how to do it. I tried with INSTR and some other solutions from different sites but it doesn't work. (P.S.: I am working in Java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `INSTR` function should work here, assuming there aren't other unmentioned problems with your data:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE INSTR(some_column, 'mark') > 0;
```